# Unable to print subscribed sensor_msgs with ROS_INFO

Tags: sensor-msgs, ros-kinetic, mavros, ros-info, subscribe

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello and thanks for reading my post.
I am trying to subscribe to a topic from an imu using the sensor_msgs::MagneticField. This topic is published by a 3rd party package called mavros. I am trying to edit the subscriber script from the tutorial, but have some issues printing the data with the ROS_INFO command. I am not sure if I am subsribing to the topic incorrectly, or if it's only an issue with my usage of ROS_INFO. I am trying to print the x variable of the message but the output message looks like this:

```
[ INFO] [1518093660.171431954]: I heard: [H?H0?`? ]
```

The documentation for the MagneticField message is [here](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/MagneticField.html)

My code looks like this

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "sensor_msgs/MagneticField.h"


void chatterCallback(const sensor_msgs::MagneticField::ConstPtr& mag)
{
  ROS_INFO("I heard: [%s]", mag->magnetic_field.x);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "listener");

  ros::NodeHandle n;


  ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe<sensor_msgs::MagneticField>("/mavros/imu/mag", 1000, chatterCallback);


  ros::spin();

  return 0;
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/282135/unable-to-print-subscribed-sensor_msgs-with-ros_info/) by [eirikaso](https://answers.ros.org/users/10741/eirikaso/) on ROS Answers with karma: 108 on 2018-02-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the error.
I had to change the [%s] with [%f] for float.
Silly mistake

---

Originally posted by [eirikaso](https://answers.ros.org/users/10741/eirikaso/) with karma: 108 on 2018-02-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0